# Conditionally change user role Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, roles, woocommerce

So here's what I want to be able to do.

I have an e-commerce site using woocommerce. I want the user to be able to provide a .edu email address to prove that they are a student, verify the email address is theirs, and then change their role to 'student' so I can then apply student discounts.

I found this question [Wordpress: Change user role conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181440/wordpress-change-user-role-conditionally)

But this isnt too useful for my needs. I'm not that great with php or woocommerce, so any assistance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom 'student' role with [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/), and use something along the lines of the code below to update your users.

```
$blogusers = get_users('');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    if(strstr($user->user_email, '.edu')) {
        set_user_role($user->ID, 'student');
    }
}
```