# Wordpress promote subscriber to contributor only by visiting a page

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I'm trying to promote my Wordpress users when they visit certain link but I'm not sure how to do that.

I found this function and placed it on the page where I want that change to be made. I though it might do the trick, but it won't:

```
function update_roles() {
   global $wpdb;
   $author = wp_get_current_user();

  $author->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
  $author->add_role( 'contributor' );
}
```

Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: @PhillHealey I've just placed it into a shortcode and onto my page. Do I need some onload parameter in order for it to work? I don't know much about PHP

Comment: In that case I'd need to see all the relevant code. Can you setup a gist or codepen and put it all in there, then I and others can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @PhillHealey I would but this is basically it :) I took it from here and stripped the posts condition, because I don't really need condition, since my only condition is that they are on the right place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181440/wordpress-change-user-role-conditionally

Comment: So how do you call the function? Whats the code for your shortcode? How & where are you using the shortcode? We need to see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_update_user( [ 'ID' =>get_current_user_id(), 'role' => 'contributor' ] );
```

You can use this code in your page template to change your user role.